# local forwarding with multiple UI

Tags: apache-spark, user-interface, airflow, ssh-tunnel

I may have a dumb question. I am running spark on a remote EC2 and I would like to use the UI it offers. According to the official doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html
I need to run the address  `http://localhost:8080` on my local browser. But when I do that I have my Airflow UI opening. How do I set it to Spark? Any help is appreciated.

Also according to this doc https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html, I tried to run `http://localhost:18080` but it did not work (I did all the settings to be able to see history server).

edit:
I have also tried the command `sc.uiWebUrl` in spark, which gives a private DNS `'http://ip-***-**-**-***.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal:4040'` . But I am not sure how do use it.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you ssh-ed into your EC2 instance using this command:

```
ssh -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name
```

To connect to the spark UI, you can add port forwarding option in ssh:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name
```

and then you can just open a browser on your local machine and go to `http://localhost:8080`.

If you need to forward multiple ports, you can chain the `-L` arguments, e.g.

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 -L 8081:localhost:8081 -i /path/my-key-pair.pem my-instance-user-name@my-instance-public-dns-name
```

Note: check the Spark port number is correct, sometimes it's 4040 and sometimes 8080, depends on how you deployed spark.